# Create a MultiClass Queue C++

Tags: c++, interface, queue

Is possible create a queue for differents types of Objects, but with same interface?

As example, I have an  interface called SensorItem, and 4 kinds of Class, SensorItemA
,SensorItemB,
SensorItemC
,SensorItemD
`

```
queue <SensorItem> cola;
void encolar(SensorItem* dato)
{
    cola.push (*dato);
}
SensorItem* sacar()
{
    SensorItem* d=cola.front();
    cola.pop();
    return d;

}
```

Thats my class Queue(Cola)
and here i try to use it

```
void main()
{
    Cola c=new Cola();
    TemperatureItem t=new TemperatureItem(3.25);
    c.encolar(t);
    ImuItem i=new ImuItem(3,4,8);
}
```

its something wrong in my syntax? or just is not possible to do it?

Comment: You should be able to achieve this with polymorphism (inheritance) by making a queue of a parent class (Sensor Items) and filling it with children of that parent class. Read up on polymorphism here if you are unfamiliar: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/

Comment: that was exactly what i did, but when i try to push items this error appears 
                                                                                                            Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void encolar(std::SensorItem *) and this is my push:             TemperatureItem t=new TemperatureItem(3.25);
    c.encolar(*t);                                                                                         TemperatureItem has inheritance from SensorItem :(

Comment: Unrelated: `main` should return an `int`, not `void`.  If you fall off the end of `main` without returning anything, the compiler will insert a `return 0` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism in C++ only works with references and pointers.  Objects in C++ are objects, not references.  If you create a `SensorItem` it will always be a `SensorItem`, not a `TemperatureItem` or a `ImuItem`.  If you have a `std::queue<SensorItem>`, it's elements will always be `SensorItem`s, never `TemperatureItem`s or `ImuItems`.

If you want to make a queue of objects derived from `SensorItem`, you need to use a queue of pointers to `SensorItem`s:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>

struct SensorItem
{
    virtual void doAThing() = 0;
    virtual ~SensorItem() {}
};

struct TemperatureItem : SensorItem
{
    void doAThing() { std::cout << "TemperatureItem\n"; }
};

struct ImuItem : SensorItem
{
    void doAThing() { std::cout << "ImuItem\n"; }
};

class Cola
{
private:
    std::queue<std::unique_ptr<SensorItem>> cola;

public:
    void encolar(std::unique_ptr<SensorItem> dato)
    {
        cola.push(std::move(dato));
    }
    std::unique_ptr<SensorItem> sacar()
    {
        std::unique_ptr<SensorItem> d = std::move(cola.front());
        cola.pop();
        return d;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Cola c;
    c.encolar(std::make_unique<TemperatureItem>());
    c.encolar(std::make_unique<ImuItem>());
    std::unique_ptr<SensorItem> item = c.sacar();
    item->doAThing();
    item = c.sacar();
    item->doAThing();
}
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8d85b30e5cbbd2a)

Here I've used `std::unique_ptr` to avoid having to do manual memory management.  You could use raw `SensorItem*`s, but I would advise against it.